# How do I open a file, passed to open as a variable?

Tags: python

```
def readfile(file):
    edges = [] # to contain tuples of all edges

    with open(file) as f: 
        for line in f:
```

I'm trying to pass in a text file called file, then read it, but it doesn't work.  Even if I cast file to a string it doesn't work.
Python says

```
with open(file) as f: IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or
filename: "<type 'file'>"
```

How do I open a file, passed to open as a variable?

Comment: How your are calling function `readfile`? seems you are not passing value for `file` argument.

Comment: This snippet should work, please post your actual code.

Comment: first of all, rename variable file. Then, it seems that you are passing a `file` object to your function, and `open` expects a string name. So there is an inconsistency here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all , as `file` is a type in python you shouldn't use it as a variable name or file name , second you need to put the file name in **quote** inside the `open` function and note that `open` function use read mod as default !  :

```
with open('file_name.txt','r') as f: 
       for line in f:
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename `file` by `filename` as `file` is a built-in name for python :

```
def readfile(filename):
    edges = [] # to contain tuples of all edges

    with open(filename) as f: 
        for line in f:
```

[`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) use 'r' as default mode.

Comment: No, `file` is not a reserved word.

Comment: Thanks Jerome, Lafada, Kasra, georg, Marius (done), stupid mistake, not passing anything in.  Doh!